# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/interceptor/AbstractBasicInterceptorProvider

Tags: java, apache, cxf

I am using apache CXF3.0.4 for consuming  a web service from my java application, I have included all the required jars files , but  I am getting below issue while using weblogic, but its working fine if I am using tomcat.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/cxf/interceptor/AbstractBasicInterceptorProvider
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Below is my pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.b2</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
       <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the cxf-api.jar in weblogic, which is in your tomcat classpath.

So remove the jat from your tomcat classpath and remove the scope provided from your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the missing class is contained in the cxf-api-2.2.3.jar which is marked as provided in your pom.

This means that this jar is there under Tomcat but it is not under weblogic.

Simply remove the provided form the scope of your dependency.